# How do i chunk an array with different sizes

Tags: javascript

I have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7 8,9,10,11,12,13]

I want to chunk this into smaller pieces but not of the same size, I want to chunk every three items then one then three and so on.

The following code will chunk the array into size of three

```js
const chunk = (cards) => {
    var chunkArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 3) {
        chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i+3));
    }
    return chunkArray;
}
cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk(cards)));
```

**Result**

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13]]

**Result I Want**

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10], [11, 12, 13]]

Comment: result you want which has 4 in first key! is it right, because in question did you mention 3,1,3,1.. so on

Comment: Do you understand how the code work? It should be pretty easy to adjust it so that takes two chunks (one of size 3 and one of size 1) out of the array during each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a while loop here, and adding an extra parameter called say chunksizes, you can then modulus the chunksize on each iteration.

I've also altered to using  while loop, as I think it fits nicer here, rather than using a for loop.

eg.

```js
const test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];

const chunk = (cards, chunksizes) => {
  const chunkArray = [];
  let cc = 0, i = 0;
  while (i < cards.length) {
    const csize = chunksizes[cc];
    chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i + csize));
    cc = (cc + 1) % chunksizes.length;
    i += csize;
  }
  return chunkArray;
}

console.log(chunk(test, [4,1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would build this atop a simpler reusable `chunk` function, using `flatMap`.  We can chunk in that pattern by chunking groups of five then chunking the results into groups of four.  This version does not use the most efficient `chunk` imaginable, and you might want to replace it with an iterative version, but I think it demonstrates the idea well:

```js
const chunk = (n) => (arr) => 
  arr .length ? [arr .slice (0, n), ... chunk (n) (arr .slice (n))] : []

const pattern4_1 = (xs) => chunk (5) (xs) .flatMap (chunk (4))

console .log(
  pattern4_1 ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
)
```

### Update

Here are variations of `chunk`, in increasing order of efficiency (at a guess; I haven't tested) and decreasing order of elegance (obvious):

```
const chunk = (n) => (xs) => 
  xs .length ? [xs .slice (0, n), ... chunk (n) (xs .slice (n))] : []

const chunk = (n) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((res, x, i) => i % n == 0 
    ? [...res, [x]] 
    : [...res.slice(0, res.length - 1), [...res[res.length - 1], x]]
  , [])


const chunk = (n) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((res, x, i) => {
    if (i % n == 0) {
      res.push([])
    }
    res[res.length - 1].push(x)
    return res
  }, [])

const chunk = (n) => (xs) => {
  const res = []
  let curr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    if (i % n == 0 && i > 0) {
      res.push (curr)
      curr = []
    }
    curr.push(xs[i])
  }
  res.push (curr)
  return res
}
```

It's often a shame that there is such a tradeoff between elegance and efficiency, but it's often the case in JS.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
const chunk = (cards) => {
  var chunkArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 3) {
    if(i%2 == 0){var state = 3} //if its even
    else{state = 0} //if its odd
    chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i+=state));
  }
  return chunkArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the index before deciding how many to slice:

```js
const chunk = (cards) => {
  var chunkArray = [];
  let j = 0; i = 0;
  while (i < cards.length) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
       chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i + 4));
       i += 4;
    } else {
       chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i + 1));
       i++;
    }
    j++;
  }
  return chunkArray;
}

console.log(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

const chunk = (cards) => {
  var chunkArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i += 5) {
    chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i, i+4));
    if(i+4<cards.length)chunkArray.push(cards.slice(i+4, i+5));
    else break
  }
  return chunkArray;
}

console.log(chunk(arr))
```